# Navegação entre telas (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, navegação

Tenho um programa de agenda e na tela principal tenho a opção de Adicionar Contato. Quando ele é clicado é aberta uma nova tela para que se possa inserir os dados. Quando o botão Salvar dessa segunda tela é ativado, ele salva os dados corretamente e fecha esse segundo stage. Porém, a lista de clientes da tela principal não é atualizada automaticamente quando isso acontece, eu preciso clicar em um botão Atualizar. Como eu faço pra chamar o metodo atualizar dessa primeira tela e atualizá-la através da segunda?

Comment: Poderia colocar trechos do código para que o pessoal possa ajudar melhor?

Answer (score 1):

Quando você for criar o segundo stage, defina o método setOnCloseRequest, como abaixo, colocando um método que carrega os dados na tabela de contatos. Quando o segundo stage for encerrado será chamado esse método.

```
segundoStage.setOnCloseRequest(event  -> {
    carregarDadosTabela();
});
```